# Kakfa 0.10.2.1 producer close method issue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We are creating new producer connections each time but in separate threads(pool of 40 and all threads will be used most of the time) and closing it when  work in done. its a java process.

Not always but sometimes close connection takes more than 10 seconds and observerd that particular message was never published.

Could you please help.

```
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  prop.put("bootstarp.servers",--);
  prop.put("acks","all");

  //some ssl properties
  ---
  //ends


    KafkaProducer connection = null;
    try { 
    connection = new KafkaProducer<String, byte[]>(props);
    msg.setTopic(topic);
    msg.setDate(new Date());
    connection.send(msg);
    } catch() {

    } finally {
    connection.close();// sometimes it takes more than 10 secs and the above message was not send
    }
```

Producer config :

max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5

acks= all

batch.size = 16384

linger.ms = 0

max.block.ms = 60000

request.timeout.ms = 5000

retries = 0

---

Updated :

If i call connection.flush() before connection.close() will it impact performance ?

As the timeout is set to 5000(request.timeout.ms) the producer sent would have failed ,, can i add retries to 1 so that message is never lost ?

Comment: You need to post a more complete code

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I added few properties, could you tel me which specific code u want me share.

Comment: Any exceptions reported? Try to catch `Exception ex` and `ex.printStackTrace`.

Comment: After this message "(KafkaProducer.java:689) - Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms."  it takes 10 secs to return and that particular message is lost .... it happened 5 times only in last 20 days.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous If i call connection.flush() before connection.close() will it impact performance ?

Comment: It shouldn’t have a major impact.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous thanks,, another question,, why would message gets lost if closing connection took more than 10 secs ?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous As the timeout is set to 5000(request.timeout.ms) the producer sent would have failed ,, can i add retries to 1 so that message is never lost ?